# Apollo client access component props with hoc and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-apollo

Breaking my head and I can't get figured out how to implement a mutation with typescript via a HOC and getting the props given to the component. For example, I want to have the 'section' name of the form but with the given example below, I receive an error

```
type FormCollectionProps = {
   mutate: any;
   section: string;
}
type FormCollectionOnSortProps = {
   oldIndex: number;
   newIndex: number;
}

const withSectionData = graphql<{}, {}, {}, FormCollectionProps>(MOVE_COLLECTION_ITEM);
const FormCollection = ({ mutate, section }: FormCollectionProps, {}) => {

   const onSortEnd = ({ oldIndex, newIndex }: FormCollectionOnSortProps) => {
      console.log('oldIndex => ', oldIndex);
      console.log('newIndex => ', newIndex);
   }

   return (
      <Query query={GET_COLLECTION_ITEMS}>
         {({ data: {{ items }}, loading, error }) => (
            <CollectionItems items={items} section={section} onSortEnd={onSortEnd} />
         )}
      </Query>
   );
};

export default withSectionData(FormCollection);
```

Implementation

```
{formSections.map((section: string) => (
  <FormCollection key={section} section={section} />
))}
```

Error

```
Type error: Type '{ key: string; section: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<{}, any, any>> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
  Property 'section' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<{}, any, any>> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.  TS2322
```

So, the 'section' prop I give is not accepted by the 'FormCollection' collection component. How can I access this property?

Comment: Wrapping your component with the `graphql` HOC will result in that component being passed a `mutate` prop, provided `MOVE_COLLECTION_ITEM` is a mutation and not a query. It's unclear from your question what the problem is -- is mutate undefined? Are you not sure how to use `mutate` inside your component?

Comment: I am sorry, you're right! I figured out that the issue wasn't the implementation of the mutation, the problem is to push down a prop on the component called 'section' which is not accepted, that's the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer;

```
type FormCollectionProps = {
   mutate?: any;
   section: string
}

type FormCollectionOnSort = {
   oldIndex: number;
   newIndex: number;
}

const withSectionData = graphql<FormCollectionProps, {}, {}, {}>(MOVE_RESUME_COLLECTION_ITEM);
```

We have to insert the 'types' for the manually added component properties as the first argument of the 'graphql' hoc. This fixed the issue.